# How to replace app engine 'parent' field with Django functionality in django-nonrel?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am looking at the challenges in converting a codebase from using [app engine patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) to using [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel).

I have existing data where Visit has a [parent entity](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Introduction) of a Patient.  So:

```
class Patient(db.Model):
  ...

class Visit(db.Model):
  ...

patient = Patient(...)
visit = Visit(parent=patient, ...)
```

How do I continue this relationship when using only django-nonrel code?  For example, how do I create a new Visit when Patient and Visit are derived from django.db.models.Model?  How do I query visits, specifying the parent Patient?  And so on.

I'm willing to use backend-specific interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found an answer: unsupported.  [Source](https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine/src/00e852c6b809/db/compiler.py#cl-390) says:

```
# for now we do not support KeyFields thus a Key has to be the own
# primary key
# TODO: GAE: support parents via GAEKeyField
assert value.parent() is None, "Parents are not yet supported!"
```